# Extract a file from tar.gz, without touching disk

Tags: bash, tar

Current Process:

1. I have a `tar.gz` file. (Actually, I have about 2000 of them, but that's another story).
2. I make a temporary directory, extract the `tar.gz` file, revealing 100,000 tiny files (around 600 bytes each).
3. For each file, I cat it into a processing program, pipe that loop into another analysis program, and save the result.

The temporary space on the machines I'm using can barely handle one of these processes at once, never mind the 16 (hyperthreaded dual quad core) that they get sent by default.
I'm looking for a way to do this process without saving to disk.  I believe the performance penalty for individually pulling files using `tar -xf $file -O <targetname>` would be prohibitive, but it might be what I'm stuck with.

Is there any way of doing this?

EDIT: Since two people have already made this mistake, I'm going to clarify:

- Each file represents one point in time.
- Each file is processed separately.
- Once processed (in this case a variant on Fourier analysis), each gives one line of output.
- This output can be combined to do things like autocorrelation across time.

EDIT2: Actual code:

```
for f in posns/*; do
    ~/data_analysis/intermediate_scattering_function < "$f"
done | ~/data_analysis/complex_autocorrelation.awk limit=1000 > inter_autocorr.txt
```

Comment: What's the total size of the uncompressed file? How much ram do you have?

Comment: 100K files * 4KB minimum file size = 400MB.  I've got 16 GB, so 16 would fit without much issue.

Comment: Well, I was going to tell you to use a ramdisk then, but @Harald Brinkhof already did :)

Comment: Just `-xf`, not `-xzf`? The title says `.tar.gz` -- but if you aren't compressed, the Python `tarfile` module will be able to seek in the file if it's opened in non-streaming mode, making random access much more efficient.

Comment: That's a typo, although I'm not opposed to unzipping first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a case where the right tool for the job is probably not a shell script. Python has a `tarfile` module which can operate in streaming mode, letting you make only a single pass through the large archive and process its files, while still being able to distinguish the individual files (which the `tar --to-stdout` approach will not).

Comment: Rewrote analysis code in python; it ran in a couple minutes instead of hours.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not care about the boundaries between files, then `tar --to-stdout -xf $file` will do what you want; it will send the contents of each file in the archive to stdout one after the other.

This assumes you are using GNU tar, which is reasonably likely if you are using bash.

[Update]

Given the constraint that you do want to process each file separately, I agree with Charles Duffy that a shell script is the wrong tool.

You could try his Python suggestion, or you could try the [Archive::Tar Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aTar).  Either of these would allow you to iterate through the tar file's contents in memory.

Comment: Unfortunately I do; each target file must be processed separately.. the output of that gets combined.

Comment: +1 This will save the overhead of creating `100000` cat processes. which is a lot of overhead saved.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tar option `--to-command=cmd` to execute the command for each file. Tar redirects the file content to the standard input of the command, and sets some environment variables with details about the file, such as TAR_FILENAME. More details in [Tar Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/extract-options.html#SEC84).

e.g.

```
tar zxf file.tar.gz --to-command='./process.sh'
```

Note that OSX uses `bsdtar` by default, which does not have this option. You can explicitly call `gnutar` instead.

Comment: Nice! This is one I didn't know. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a ramdisk ( http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html ) to process and load it from. (me boldly assuming you use Linux but other UNIX systems should have the same type of provisions)

Comment: I was considering tmpfs; that requires me to convince an admin to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar zxvf <file.tar.gz> <path_to_extract> --to-command=cat
```

The above command will show the content of extracted file on shell only. There will be no changes to disk. tar command should be GNU tar.

Sample logs:

```
$ cat file_a
aaaa
$ cat file_b
bbbb
$ cat file_c
cccc
$ tar zcvf file.tar.gz file_a file_b file_c
file_a
file_b
file_c
$ cd temp
$ ls <== no files in directory
$ tar zxvf ../file.tar.gz file_b --to-command=cat
file_b
bbbb
$ tar zxvf ../file.tar.gz file_a --to-command=cat
file_a
aaaa
$ ls  <== Even after tar extract - no files in directory. So, no changes to disk
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.25
...
$
```